# Pine Script strategy tester opens position in wrong candle

Tags: pine-script

I'm testing a strategy in Pine Script, as shown in the image for visual debugging I've plotted open/sl/tp values on the chart, which is what I desire from the strategy. But when I try to open the position with the given values, position will be opened in the next candle when the buy or sell signal is detected.

[image: wrongly opened position]

Here is the code:

```
[buyTP, buySL] = TPSL('long')
[sellTP, sellSL] = TPSL('short')

// Visual debug of trade signals
openPlot = plot(buySignal or sellSignal ? open : na, color=color.orange, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4)
buySLPlot = plot(buySignal ? buySL : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4)
sellSLPlot = plot(sellSignal ? sellSL : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4)
buyTPPlot = plot(buySignal ? buyTP : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4)
sellTPPlot = plot(sellSignal ? sellTP : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4)
fill(openPlot, buySLPlot, color.new(color.red, 70))
fill(openPlot, buyTPPlot, color.new(color.green, 70))
fill(openPlot, sellSLPlot, color.new(color.red, 70))
fill(openPlot, sellTPPlot, color.new(color.green, 70))



if buySignal
    [tp, sl] = TPSL('long')
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

if sellSignal
    [tp, sl] = TPSL('short')
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)
    
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("close long", 'long', limit=buyTP, stop=buySL)    
else if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit('close short', 'short', limit=sellTP, stop=sellSL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strategy.entry will always enter the strategy in the next candles open. Assuming that you want to enter a trade in any candles open, you will be having the buy and sell singal beforehand. So you can call Strategy.entry in previous bar itself

Comment: Very strange! So it's not possible to open a position at current market price?
I'm coming from MQ4 (MetaTrader) world which it was possible.

Comment: Well even logically, if you are generating a singal based on something that happened in that candle, code should not be allowed to go back in time to buy at candle open

Comment: Yep that's right, but when the signal comes, I have to wait the whole candle to be closed and then open the position at the open price of new candle. I thought maybe there is a way to open position in the current market price?

Comment: Depending on the calculation. I have been working with indicators and strategies for a while for my trading-bot. The difference I found is when building the entry using an indicator to send an alert to the trading-bot, you would use values that have occurred with no repainting e.g. if high[1] > high[2], replicating this for the strategy side, you need to bring forward the calculation for the current bar therefore it would be high > high[1] which creates the same entry if I had a signal from an indicator vs signal entry from a strategy.

Comment: pinescript execute your code on each bar close => your code 'see nothing' between each iteration. Between each iteration, only an exit.order can be executed on a reached TP or SL.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to use **process_orders_on_close=true**.

Example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Long Name", shorttitle="Short Name", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)
```